# Internal Server Error (500) when creating a document in DocumentDB from data passed on from Console Application to ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an **ASP.NET WebAPI Controller** which **creates a document in Azure DocumentDB from the data passed on to its POST method from a Console app**. The **return type** of the POST method **is HttpResponseMessage** which **returns a status code for OK (i.e. 200) when the document has been successfully created**.

The **document gets created successfully** from the WebAPI and the **status code 200 is returne**d too. But somewhere then it goes wrong (which I can't figure out where and why) and the **status code** that my **Console app receives after the successful POST is 500** - an Internal Server Error occurred.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]GPSDataVM data) 
{ 
    if (KeyRepository.IsValid(data.Key)) 
    { 
        // Creates a document in DocumentDB by calling an async method CreateLiveDataDocument(data); 
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
    } 

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized); 
}
```

Can anyone help me out with the situation? Thanks in advance ..

Comment: If the console receives 500, how do you know the server returned 200?

Comment: Please post the code in your controller and the error response you are getting.

Comment: I had put a break-point in my WebAPI Controller to check the status code which is getting returned to the Console app. There I found it to be 200.

Comment: @ArnabChakraborty - public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]GPSDataVM data)
{
            if (KeyRepository.IsValid(data.Key))
            {
                // Creates a document in DocumentDB by calling an async method
                CreateLiveDataDocument(data);
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem from the following address:
[Web Api + HttpClient: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060214/web-api-httpclient-an-asynchronous-module-or-handler-completed-while-an-async)

I changed the definition to my WebAPI Controller to:

```
public **async Task<HttpResponseMessage>** Post([FromBody]GPSDataVM data) {
        if (KeyRepository.IsValid(data.Key))
        {
            // Creates a document in DocumentDB by calling an async method
            **// Code for CreateLiveDataDocument(data)**
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized); }
```